# Git merge is not merging

Tags: git

I have two branches *master* and *branch1*.

In the branch *master*, I have one file *file.txt* and contents of the file is below.

```
master
```

This branch contains only single commit. If I run the command `git log --oneline`, I get below output.

> 76ece5b (HEAD -> master) first commit  - master

Now I created the branch *branch1* from the last commit of master, which is mentioned above.

Now I changed the content of the file to below.

Note: - Line 1 is empty.

```
branch1
```

Now I have committed and If I run the command `git log --oneline`, I get below output.

> 90b1eca (HEAD -> branch1) branch1 first commit
> 76ece5b (master) first commit  - master

From this branch itself, I am trying to merge with master with the command `git merge master`, and I was expecting the content of file will be merged and must looks like below.

```
master 
branch1
```

But I am getting the below message and content of the file remains the same as in the last commit of branch1.

```
Already up to date.
```

Due to above Error I am not able to merge. Need to understand why this is happening and how can I merge.

Comment: There is nothing to *merge* in the sense that you're combining changes, since you have a linear history. A *merge* in this case is just a fast-forward of the current branch to the newest commit. Note that in the commit `90b1eca` you *explicitly deleted* the first line of the file, so the most up-to-date version of that file is missing that line.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand anything. Could you please explain with more detail ?

Comment: Even `--no-ff`  is not working and giving the same message

Comment: @eftshift0 the OP is asking about merging `master` into `branch1`, not merging `branch1` into `master`.

Comment: Oh! You are completely right. Let me delete my explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The command `git merge master` merges ON the branch where you are (`branch1`) the changes made on the `master` after the last merge.

In this case, the `master` is behind of one commit (that contains the deletion of one row and a new one), so you have nothing to merge.

[image]

As you can see, the `branch1` is an evolution of `master` and since the moment you branch them, the `master` has not evolved, so there are no changes to merge.

If you do **the opposite** (switch to `master` and request `git merge branch1`), you will align `master` with the `branch1` obtaining:

```
branch1
```

What you will see is the "*new merge commit*" of merge on the `master` branch.

[image: merge on master]

**Another way to see this effect**

Maybe this exercise can be helpful to understand the mechanics: commit two different new lines on the same file of both branches

you will have on `master` branch:

```
master
a new line
```

you will have on `branch1` branch

```
master
branch1
```

When you merge, you will get a sum of the changes (and, depending on the difference, maybe a conflict).

The result will be something like:

```
master
a new line
branch1
```

And on the graph you see one of these cases (left for merge ON `master` and right for merge ON `branch1`):

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer.

What I understood that Git maintain series of commit where each commit has detail of its previous commit.We have different kind of pointers like HEAD and Branch Pointers. With the help of these pointer we can traverse through the entire series of commits.

Now Suppose, Currently I have a only one branch which is a master , If I create new branch from the master , What I essentially doing is that I am creating new pointer that also pointing to same commit which are being pointed by master. If I do any new commits in the new branch , I am essentially moving my new branch pointer to latest commits leaving behind where master is pointing.This also implies that In new commit , old commits contents are being preseved that also implies last commits always has most updated version of file. Now If I try to my merge my new branch with my master branch , I am essentially merging my latest file with old file that does not make any sense because most updated version suppose to be preserve the old commit contents. If I have intentionally removed it that means I am aware I don't require it anymore, which is my case.

Comment: Let me put it this way: you can only merge what is **not** part of your history already. In your experiment, the commit that `master` is pointing to is already in the history of `branch1` _hence_ nothing to commit, you are up-to-date in terms of having everything pointed to by `master` in your history alrteady.